Python dominate do not escape characters
I am using dominate to create an HTML document in Python. In one part of my workflow there is an already hardcoded HTML code in a string which I want to insert inside a tag similarly as innerHTML would do in JavaScript. However, I cannot figure out how to do this, because it always escapes the special HTML characters (as you would normally want to do):
import dominate

hardcoded_html_string = 'Hello, <em>how are you doin?</em>'

doc = dominate.tags.html(title='doc')

with doc:
    dominate.tags.p(
        text = hardcoded_html_string,
        # do_not_escape_HTML_chars = True, # I would like to have this!
    )

print(doc)

prints
<html title="doc">
  <p>Hello, &lt;em&gt;how are you doin?&lt;/em&gt;</p>
</html>

and my expected result is
<html title="doc">
  <p>Hello, <em>how are you doin?<em></p>
</html>

How can I achieve this?

I found the solution using dominate.util.raw in this way:
import dominate

hardcoded_html_string = 'Hello, <em>how are you doin?</em>'

doc = dominate.tags.html(title='doc')

with doc:
    dominate.tags.p(
        text = dominate.util.raw(hardcoded_html_string),
    )

print(doc.render(pretty=False))

This is documented in the readme.md file.
